# Email sent via servlet using JavaMail API not getting through

Tags: java, email, servlets, smtp, jakarta-mail

Below is my code that gives me no error, but the email is not received in my account as well. I went through all the posts that were there about this thing and modified my code accordingly. I am really new to this thing so this question might appear to be silly, but still any directions/suggestions are welcome. Also the servlet will be running on google app engine. And I'm using my gmail account username and password instead of `abc@gmail.com` and password. Thanks.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class UserFeedback extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
{
    sendFeedback(req, res);
}

private void sendFeedback(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{
    String from = null, sub = null, msg = null;
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com", username = "abc@gmail.com", password = "password";
    Session session = null;
    MimeMessage email = null;
    Transport transport = null;

    sub = req.getParameter("subject");
    from = req.getParameter("sender");
    msg = req.getParameter("message");
    msg = "From: " + from + "\n" + msg;

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator(){ protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@gmail.com", "password");}});
    session.setDebug(true);

    email = new MimeMessage(session);
    try 
    {
        email.setSender(new InternetAddress(username));
        email.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("abc@gmail.com"));
        email.setSubject(sub);
        email.setContent(msg, "text/plain");
    }
    catch (AddressException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (MessagingException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try 
    {
        Transport.send(email);
    } 
    catch (NoSuchProviderException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MessagingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: have you checked junk folder?

Comment: yes I did check my spam/junk folder; The mail is not there either.

Comment: Oh yes and one thing is that I'm trying to send the mail to the same account since I'm testing it, but I don't think that would cause any problem; I'm not sure though.

Comment: Ok, while I was searching around for the solution, I came across Google Application Specific Password. Now I wonder whether I should use my original password while authentication or use the google generated password for my app?

Comment: The main idea behind doing this is I'm trying to get user feedback as an email into my google account using Java Servlet. Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: Are you using the latest mail.jar ?

Comment: See the JavaMail FAQ for debugging tips.  Also, 1) change getDefaltInstance to getInstance, and 2) you don't need all that socket factory stuff (see the FAQ).  You may still have a Gmail-specific problem, but the FAQ will help you debug it.

Comment: JavaMail FAQ can be found here:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the many Facade implementations for JavaMail. Will clean your code up considerably.

To find out if this code works, write a unit test and use either:

- [Wiser](http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/wiki/Wiser)
- [Dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/)

This will get you an answer fast

Answer (score 0):

You are using :

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
```

Use this instead :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
```

If it doesn't help post the server logs which shows that the email is being sent already.

Answer (score 0):

This is one type of send mail application.....
And its static application ,its worked and we had developed dynamic application from this only..so try it once..
Add this jar files 
dsn.jar,imap.jar,mailapi.jar,pop3.jar,smtp.jar.

```
package Javamail;
/*
Some SMTP servers require a username and password authentication before you
can use their Server for Sending mail. This is most common with couple
of ISP's who provide SMTP Address to Send Mail.

This Program gives any example on how to do SMTP Authentication
(User and Password verification)

This is a free source code and is provided as it is without any warranties and
it can be used in any your code for free.

*/

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/*
  To use this program, change values for the following three constants,
    SMTP_HOST_NAME -- Has your SMTP Host Name
    SMTP_AUTH_USER -- Has your SMTP Authentication UserName
    SMTP_AUTH_PWD  -- Has your SMTP Authentication Password
  Next change values for fields
  emailMsgTxt  -- Message Text for the Email
  emailSubjectTxt  -- Subject for email
  emailFromAddress -- Email Address whose name will appears as "from" address
  Next change value for "emailList".
  This String array has List of all Email Addresses to Email Email needs to be sent to.
  Next to run the program, execute it as follows,
  SendMailUsingAuthentication authProg = new SendMailUsingAuthentication();
*/

public class SendmailUsejavamail
{

  private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.gmail.com";
  private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "aaaa@gmail.com";
  private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD  = "xxxxxxxxx";

  private static final String emailMsgTxt      = "Online Order Confirmation Message. Also include the Tracking Number.";
  private static final String emailSubjectTxt  = "Order Confirmation Subject";
  private static final String emailFromAddress = "bbbbb@gmail.com";

  // Add List of Email address to who email needs to be sent to
  private static final String[] emailList = {"abc@gmail.com", "abcd@gmail.com"};

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    SendmailUsejavamail smtpMailSender = new SendmailUsejavamail();
    smtpMailSender.postMail( emailList, emailSubjectTxt, emailMsgTxt, emailFromAddress);
    System.out.println("Sucessfully Sent mail to All Users");
  }

  public void postMail( String recipients[ ], String subject,
                            String message , String from) throws MessagingException
  {
    boolean debug = false;

     //Set the host smtp address
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
     props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
    session.setDebug(debug);

    // create a message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // set the from and to address
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
    msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
    InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++)
    {
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
    }
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
    // Setting the Subject and Content Type
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
    Transport.send(msg);
 }
/**
* SimpleAuthenticator is used to do simple authentication
* when the SMTP server requires it.
*/
private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator
{

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER;
        String password = SMTP_AUTH_PWD;
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
}

}
```